# git won't commit because a deleted file doesn't exist

Tags: git, git-add

It appears that I've somehow gotten `git` into a state in which it won't commit because a file that's been deleted doesn't exist:

```
~/src$ git status -u
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD ..." to unstage)
#
#   deleted:    release-vars.sh
#
~/src$ git commit -a
fatal: pathspec 'release-vars.sh' did not match any files
~/src$ ls release-vars.sh
ls: cannot access release-vars.sh: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this situation?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this? [git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458306/git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files)

Comment: Not really, that is for a special case dealing with LARGE files, not the trivial one file case.

Comment: Is this an issue with case sensitivity on the file system?

Comment: Just recreate the file: `touch release-vars.sh`, commit, then delete it cleanly through git

Answer (score 2):

`-a` is explicitly telling it to commit the current version of every currently-tracked file from the content in your worktree.  It's not quite the same operation as

```
git add --all
```

which might be what you're after here.  Then do an ordinary commit.

If your `.gitignore` specs leave unignored detritus you don't want to track you could instead `git rm --cached` the deleted file explicitly so your subsequent `git commit -a` doesn't trip over the unexpectedly missing file.

Comment: It does the delete on my system.  What does commit say when you do `git add --all` before committing?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest starting by staging your changes manually using `git add FILENAME` and `git rm FILENAME` before doing a commit without the `-a` option.  (i.e. just go `git commit -m "SOME MESSAGE"` )

`git commit -a` says to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted. When you are trying to remove a file from git that may still exist locally this will be problematic.

Being explicit about what you are doing is rarely a bad thing and may easily resolve the problem.

If that doesn't work; try doing `git reset` and then try this fresh.

Another option provided by `git help rm` is as follows:

> If all you really want to do is to remove from the index the files
>   that are no longer present in the working tree (perhaps because your
>   working tree is dirty so that you cannot use git commit -a), use the
>   following command:
>
> ```
>        git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D -z | xargs -0 git rm --cached
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But what do I do now?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson Have you tried to commit without the `-a` option? Just a bare `git commit`?

Comment: @SteveEmmerson what happens, if you try git `rm --cached release-vars.sh` and then `git commit -m "remove release-vars.sh"`