# is it possible to completely delete a Git branch?

Tags: git, branch

I read that, normally, deleted branches can be resurrected.

I'm looking for a way to completely obliterate a branch.

One of the developers stuck 2Gb worth of assets inside that branch, which really is content and shouldn't be inside the repo.

Note: I've not merged it into master yet!

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/a/25458504/1860929 could help you; You will have to do something very similar.

Comment: @mu無 that deals with specific files. I need something simpler, rm -rf branch.

Comment: @salivan, you say you want a simpler solution but you may not have that option. If the problematic files were merged into another branch (`master` in your case), then they're in that branch too. You can't just delete the other branch and expect to see your repository size shrink.

Comment: Have you the option to "redo" the merge? Speaks throwing away the old merge commit and creating a new one? I might have something in mind then.

Comment: @Zeeker yes! I can do that :) I didn't merge it in master yet.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do this trivially through the use of `git filter-branch`.  E.g, assuming that the files to be removed are in a directory called `content`:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf content' --prune-empty
```

This will iterate over all the commits in your branch, removing the erroneous content from any commits in which it occurs.

Answer (score 4):

I want to add that I personally prefer the `filter-branch` approach, since this doesn't involve the loss of history. If `filter-branch` seems too difficult to use, you can take a look at [BFG Repo-cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) which is simpler.

Nevertheless I will provide an alternative for completness sake.

---

Since you said in the comments, that you have the option to throw away the old merge and create a new one, I would like to suggest that you create a *squash merge*.

Let's assume your repository has a history similar to this.

```
* The merge commit [master]
|\
| * feature commit [feature]
| |
| * feature commit (the evil one)
. .
. . (some more commits)
. .
|/
*
```

First things first, we will undo the merge.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Now we merge *feature* again, but this time use the `--squash` option. When doing this, git won't create a usual merge commit (speaks multiple parents), but it will apply all changes from the *feature* branch and leave your working tree in a state as if a "usual" merge happened ([take a look at the documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)).

```
git merge --squash feature
```

Now you can resolve possible conflicts and then simply commit the merged changes (`git commit`). However, note that such a merge obviously has no reference on the history of the merged branch (in this case *feature*); you should include that information in the commit message.

Assuming that there are no other references onto *feature* - except for the actual branch - you can now continue to delete the branch, followed by a [garbage collection](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html).

```
git branch -D feature
git gc
```

You have to realise that `git gc` will **only remove** the history and *blobs* of the *feature* branch, if you have **no other reference** pointing to them. You have to make sure that this is the case.

---

### Important

`git gc` will not only remove the history of the *feature* branch but each *dangling object*. To better understand the implications and consequences I would suggest to read the [*Git Internals - Maintenance and Data Recovery*](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery) chapter of the progit book.