# How to remove a folder within a github repo that was deleted locally?

Tags: git, github

I've multiple folders in one repo. Originally was working on folder3 and pushed commits. Then I decided to change the name of my folder3 to folder3A and pushed to github. Then I deleted the folder3 locally using `rm -rf folder3` and then pushed the commit. Now the problem is none of the below commands work if i want to remove the folder3 in my github repo since the file is not found locally: 
`git rm -r --cached folder3`, `git rm -rf obj` both gives this error: `fatal: pathspec 'folder3' did not match any files`. How do I remove just one folder that has been deleted locally but is still present on github?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458306/git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files

Comment: Did you checkout the branch before trying to remove? Run git checkout branchname and then remove.

Comment: I'm confused when you say that you *"decided to change the name of my folder3 to folder3A ... Then I deleted the folder3"* Does that mean that you made a copy of `folder3` as `folder3A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add everything in that is in your directory right now and have github sync with your folder.

```
git add * 
git commit -m "removed a folder"
git push origin master
```

Comment: my authentication had failed and I was trying to push.