# Github, file too large already deleted.

Tags: file, github

I had a file that I tried to add to my repo but is over the github limit. Unfortunately I deleted it but when I do a push it still tried add it.

```
rm dist/img/work.zip
fatal: pathspec 'dist/img/work.zip' did not match any files
```

How do I get it out the repo?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch).

1. Use the command

   ```
   git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
     'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch dist/img/work.zip' \
     --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
   ```
2. After the filter branch is complete, verify that no unintended file was lost.
3. Now add a .gitignore rule

   ```
   echo dist/img/work.zip >> .gitignore
   git add .gitignore && git commit -m "ignore rule for files"
   ```
4. Now do a push

   ```
   git push -f origin branch
   ```

Adapted from: [git rm - fatal: pathspec did not match any files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458306/git-rm-fatal-pathspec-did-not-match-any-files)