# Git ignore and untrack file [Yes I already readed the other posts]

Tags: linux, git, gitignore, git-untracked

I put some folders in my gitignore but as described in the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected

So I have to untrack some files and is where my nightmare start

This is my gitignore file

```
$ cat .gitignore
/.settings/
/.buildpath
/configuration.php
/administrator/cache/*
/images/*
/connectionOracle.php
/administrator/components/com_jsecure/*
/administrator/language/en-GB/*
```

The last modification made in this file was the addition of the line /images/*

To untrack this folder i follow as described {1}[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964297/untrack-files-from-git) and {2}[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1274447/4175515)

Following {1}

```
$ git update-index --assume-unchanged images/*
fatal: Unable to mark file images/02102012_planos.jpg
```

Question 1: Why can't untrack this specific file?

Following {2}

```
$ git rm --cached images/ -r
fatal: pathspec 'images' did not match any files
```

Same result with specific file

```
$ git rm --cached images/20130626tabela1.jpg
fatal: pathspec 'images/20130626tabela1.jpg' did not match any files
```

Question 2: Why I receive this error message? Searching here lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931542/4175515) but, as I said, these files under /images/ are tracked.

And the Cake Cherry

To verify the list of ignored file I ran this command

```
$git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

That give me a very long list of files inside the images, administrator and mpdf61 folder. 
     The mpdf61 folder is not configured in the gitignore file and neither in info/exclude.

```
Question 3: Why the mpdf61 appears in this list?
```

Comment: Can you show the results of `git status`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: "tracked" means "in the index".  "Untracked" means "not in the index".  The display of a files untracked-ness is normally suppressed if it's also ignored, so some prefer to call files whose state is "both untracked and ignored" just "ignored", quietly glossing over their "untracked"-ness.  Note that the index need not match the current `HEAD` commit: that's how you prepare the *next* commit, by making changes to the index.  Those changes become part of a permanent commit only once you make the commit, and the act of making that commit updates `HEAD` as well.

---

> ```
> $ git update-index --assume-unchanged images/*
> fatal: Unable to mark file images/02102012_planos.jpg
> ```
>
> Question 1: Why can't untrack this specific file?

You can't untrack it because it's not tracked.  Moreover, `git update-index --assume-unchanged` does not untrack a file in the first place.  For `update-index` to update the "assume unchanged" bit, the file must be in the index, so that `update-index` has something to update.  This `fatal` error occurs with the first such untracked (not-in-the-index) file.  Nothing else happens to any of the subsequent files named by the shell's expansion of `*`, as `update-index` just stops after the first error.

(For instance, if you run `git update-index --assume-unchanged red.txt blue.jpg green.svg`, and both `red.txt` and `green.svg` *are* in the index while `blue.jpg` is *not* in the index, `update-index` will mark the index entry for `red.txt` but not the one for `green.svg`.)

---

> ```
> $ git rm --cached images/20130626tabela1.jpg
> fatal: pathspec 'images/20130626tabela1.jpg' did not match any files
> ```
>
> Question 2: Why I receive this error message?

Because that file is also not tracked (not in the index) and therefore cannot be removed from the index.  This:

> ```
> $ git rm --cached images/ -r
> fatal: pathspec 'images' did not match any files
> ```

means that *no* `images/` files are (now) in the index.  (Perhaps some were before, and are therefore in the `HEAD` commit, but no longer are, after an earlier successful `git rm --cached`; if so, they should show up in  `git status` as "deleted".)

---

> ```
> $ git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
> ```
>
> That give me a very long list of files inside the images, administrator and mpdf61 folder. The mpdf61 folder is not configured in the gitignore file and neither in info/exclude.
>
> Question 3: Why the mpdf61 appears in this list?

Presumably because those file are ignored.  There are three "standard" exclusion file classes, as shown in the `git ls-files` documentation:

> `--exclude-standard`
>          Add the standard Git exclusions: .git/info/exclude, .gitignore **in each directory, *and* the user's global exclusion file**.

(all emphasis mine).  You said "the" (as in one) gitignore file, but there may be many, including one within the directory `mpdf61` itself, and you may have a `core.excludesFile` configured.

To find which ignore directive is ignoring a specific file, use `git check-ignore -v`.  See [the `git check-ignore` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-check-ignore.html).